# MS Access Selecting distinct rows

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have table similar to this:

```
ID ProductName Price
1  Water       0.89
1  Water       0.99
1  Water       0.79
2  Coke        1.99
3  Sprite      1.99
```

What I would like is to get is the lowest price of every product. ( ID can't change for same name ) If I could group just by one column it would be fine but I can't since Access doesn't let me. My current code that I've been trying to deal with is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Products.ProductName, Products.Price
FROM Products
GROUP BY Products.ProductName, Products.Price
```

Information that I would like to get should look like:

```
ProductName Price
Water       0.79
Coke        1.99
Sprite      1.99
```

Comment: `SELECT MIN(Products.ProductName), MIN(Products.Price)
FROM Products
GROUP BY Products.ID` ?

Comment: Yup that worked. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use an aggregation on the product name (or id):

```
SELECT Products.ProductName, MIN(Products.Price) as Price
FROM Products
GROUP BY Products.ProductName;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are very close to it. Just use `min()` function:

```
SELECT Products.ProductName, min(Products.Price)
FROM Products
GROUP BY Products.ProductName;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT P.ProductName, 
       MIN(P.Price) as Price
FROM Products p
GROUP BY P.ProductName
```